# Simplify relation involving Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

I have a sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^T(-1)^{T-k}(k!)^2{n\brace k}\binom{n-k}{T-k}.
$$
Is it possible to simplify it? Ideally Stirling numbers should disappear.

EDIT: I was asked about context. This is from a problem, where one should find a coefficient at $x^T$ obtained after summing polynomials $c_kk!x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$, where $c_k$ appear to be the sequence http://oeis.org/A019538 or $k!{n\brace k}$. I wouldn't want to say more about where these polynomials come from, cause this is from a programming contest. Not ongoing - it's from the last year's - but still... The formula checks out for small values of $T$ and $n$, but I need it for large ones.

Comment: own efforts?!?!

Comment: All I have is if you combine one $k!$ with Stirling number, you get this sequence on oeis: http://oeis.org/A019538 . It led me nowhere.

Comment: Substitute
\begin{eqnarray*}
k!\begin{Bmatrix}n\\k\end{Bmatrix} =\sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-i} \binom{k}{i} i^n 
\end{eqnarray*}
Invert the order of the sums, lets us know how you get on ... good luck $\ddot \smile$

Comment: It might be useful to know where this sum comes from. A bit of context, please.

Comment: Context added. Thanks.

Comment: If anyone's interested, I generated a series of these sums, plugged them into oeis and it turned out they are Eulerian numbers, for which somewhat fast explicit formula involving only binomial coefficients and powers of numbers is available.